# Avoid adding element to array if it's been added before

Tags: javascript

I have a very hard time formulating my question, I hope you guys understand what I mean.
Is there a way to make sure elements never end up together again?
Example, If A, B, C and D has been in the same new array before, they shouldn't be able to be together again.

This is my code,

```
let xGrps = 3; // Number of groups
let xSize = 4; // Number of items per group
let allItems = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']; // All Items
let newGrps = []; // New groups

for (let i = 0; i < xGrps; i++) {
    let tempGrp = "";
    for(let j = 0; j < xSize; j++) {
        tempGrp += allItems[0] + ",";
        allItems.shift();
    }
    newGrps[i] = tempGrp;
    console.log(newGrps[i]);
}
```

I belive I should use something like this maybe,

```
let blockGrps = [{
    A: ['B'],
    B: ['C','D'],
    C: ['E'],
    // and so on 
}];
```

Comment: I don't understand the expected output. You have there an array with just one element, while your code suggests an array with many elements. That single element has "A" , "B", "C" properties... where do you get those names from? Are they related to the input? Why would "A" have an array with 1 element, and "B" an array with 2 elements? What is the logic? Can you give a consistent example of input and output?

Comment: Imagine having 12 persons. When you click a button you are going to divide them into 3 groups with 4 persons each. Next time you click the button, you are dividing these 12 persons into 3 groups again. But they can't be in a group with the same people they have been in group with before.
So if A,B,C and D was in the group before, A can not be in the same group as B,C and D again.

Comment: @Shamaran And how many times that button will be clicked? Do you know that at some point, you will not be able to follow this procedure, don't you? Are you coding something like round robin for a multiplayer game? Can you give us the context where it applies?

Comment: Anyway, I would create an available pairs matrix. Initially each letter could be paired with any other letter, and according as they will be grouped, you could remove them from the available pairs matrix. When the available pairs matrix becomes empty, there will be no more action for the button.